# Calculating no of weekends in between the two given date and time fields by considering the time difference and output the difference in minutes

Tags: c#

I have two fields startdate and enddate. I need to calculate how many weekends in between two date and time fields and show the result in minutes.

For example start date is `01/11/2019 00:00:00` and end date as `03/11/2019 11:00:00`. Below code is returning the difference in minutes correctly as `2100 minutes` but when I keep the dates as`02/11/2019 08:00` and `03/11/2019 00:00` I am getting the result as `1440` but my expected result is `960` minutes.

I understand that's because I am adding `1440` in code so how to correct this?

```
public double CountOfWeekEnds(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {          
        double weekEndCount = 0;
        if (startDate > endDate)
        {
            DateTime temp = startDate;
            startDate = endDate;
            endDate = temp;
        }
        TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;
        int days = diff.Days;
        for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
        {
            var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
            if (testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {

                    if (testDate.Date < endDate.Date)
                    {
                        weekEndCount += 1440; // 24h * 60 min
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                    var todayStart = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);

                       var difference = (endDate - todayStart).TotalMinutes;
                        weekEndCount += difference;
                    }                  
            }
        }
        return weekEndCount;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, just to be clear. You want to calculate the number of weekend minutes, within your timespan?

Comment: YES, That's correct. Thank you Noceo

Comment: well, if not first or last, assume 24hours, if not sat or sun add 0 else add max mins, then sort out first and last day depending on times specified

Comment: @BugFinder - Could you please show that in code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to remain as much of the original code as possible, only three minor changes have to be made:

---

### 1. Use the actual dates to calculate diff:

`TimeSpan diff = endDate.Date - startDate.Date;` instead of `TimeSpan diff = endDate - startDate;`

This is because later in the upcoming for-loop you are trying to evaluate each date in order to say if is a saturday or sunday. Otherwise, you are evaluating if the date 24 (, 48, …) hours after your starting time stamp is a saturday or sunday.

---

### 2. Use `testDate` instead of `todayStart` in order to calculate `difference`

```
difference = (endDate - testDate).TotalMinutes;
```

instead of

```
var todayStart = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
var difference = (endDate - todayStart).TotalMinutes;
```

This is because testDate does contain the hours and minutes to calculate the difference in minutes. Otherwise you are just ignoring the day time of the starting day. Note that this correction can lead to a negative difference value if the startDate day time is later than the endDate day time.

---

### 3. do not add a whole day if there is only one day to examine in total

That means that if startDate.Date == endDate.Date, you should just calculate the difference between the dates.

```
if (testDate.Date < endDate.Date && startDate.Date != endDate.Date)
```

This has to be done because of the code logic: a full day is added for every new day other than the final day and for the final day ~24hours are added or substracted to the final value depending on the day times of the startDate and endDate.

---

### The complete corrected code:

```
public static double CountOfWeekEnds(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{          
    double weekEndCount = 0;
    if (startDate > endDate)
    {
        DateTime temp = startDate;
        startDate = endDate;
        endDate = temp;
    }

    TimeSpan diff = endDate.Date - startDate.Date; //instead of endDate - startDate
    int days = diff.Days; 

    for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
    {
        var testDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
        //Console.WriteLine(testDate);
        if (testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) //only weekends count
        {

            if (testDate.Date < endDate.Date && startDate.Date != endDate.Date) { // added  startDate.Date != endDate.Date
                weekEndCount += 1440; // 24h * 60 min
                //Console.WriteLine("************************add 1440 ");
            }
            else
            {    
                double difference;
                difference = (endDate - testDate).TotalMinutes; //instead of endDate -  todayStart
                //Console.WriteLine("************************add " + difference);
                weekEndCount += difference;
            }                  
        }
    }
    //return days;
    return weekEndCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, i simplified what i said a little down to:

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2019,11,1,0,0,0);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2019, 11, 3, 11, 0, 0);

        TimeSpan diff = end - start;

        Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalDays);

        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<Math.Ceiling(diff.TotalDays); i++)
        {
            DateTime test = start.AddDays(i);
            Console.WriteLine(test.DayOfWeek);
            if (test.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||  test.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)

            {
                if (test.Date==start.Date)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("start");
                    total += (23 - start.Hour) * 60 + (60 - start.Minute);
                }
                else if (test.Date==end.Date)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("end");
                    total += end.Hour * 60 + end.Minute;
                }
                else
                {

                    total += 24 * 60;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(test + " total " + total);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.WriteLine(total);
```

which counts all saturdays and sundays and allows for start and ends to be partials

(and can someone send a keyboard with actual keys this membrain lark is hampering typings)

Comment: Hi BugFinder, While I am testing the above code, with the following examples I am getting wrong calculations. Please can you have a look Start date as 02/11/2019 00:00 and 02/11/2019 16:00

Comment: OK, Thank you, I thought there is some bug in code that's why I came back to you. I will work it out to fix the issue.

Comment: I never said it handled same day :P however, it shouldnt be hard to fix, at the same time it will help you understand it better if you work out why rather than i just fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (somewhat) simple solution. Please note that the code could (and probably should) be refactored if it was to be production code. But I tried to optimize it for understandability, since it was your first post...

```
public static int CalculateWeekendMinutes(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    int weekendMinutes = 0;

    // First and last day will be handled seperately in the end
    var firstFullDay = start.AddDays(1).Date;
    var lastFullDay = end.AddDays(-1).Date;

    TimeSpan limitedSpan = lastFullDay - firstFullDay;
    int spanLengthDays = (int)limitedSpan.TotalDays;

    var dateIterator = firstFullDay;

    // Looping over the limited span allows us to analyse all the full days
    while (dateIterator <= lastFullDay)
    {
        if (dateIterator.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dateIterator.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            weekendMinutes += (24 * 60);
        }   
        dateIterator = dateIterator.AddDays(1);
    }

    // Finally we can calculate the partial days and add that to our total
    weekendMinutes += CalculateMinutesOnFirstDay(start);
    weekendMinutes += CalculateMinutesOnLastDay(end);

    return weekendMinutes;
}

// Helps us calculate the minutes of the first day in the span
private static int CalculateMinutesOnFirstDay(DateTime date)
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        // We want to know how many minutes there are UNTIL the next midnight
        int minutes = (int)(date.Date.AddDays(1) - date).TotalMinutes;
        return minutes;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Helps us calculate the minutes of the last day in the span
private static int CalculateMinutesOnLastDay(DateTime date)
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        // We want to know how many minutes there are SINCE the last midnight
        int minutes = (int)(date - date.Date).TotalMinutes;
        return minutes;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Noceo, Above code is giving wrong answer if I take 31/10/2019 00:00 and 04/11/2019 12:00 as example. Please can you have a look. Thanks

Comment: My bad, I forgot some stuff while moving code around. It should work now. Though for a production implementation, I would use the solution of @BugFinder, albeit with a bit more comments :-)

Comment: OK, Thank you - Noceo

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at this condition:

if (testDate.Date < endDate.Date)

It means that "as long as the ticks of testDate is less than the ticks of endDate".
This condition will be true for all conditions that makes your variable "days" positive.

I think you need to extend this, condition e.g. 
if ((endDate - todayStart).TotalMinutes > 1440 )

This way it will check whether it is AT LEAST 24 hours earlier. If it isn't it should go forth with your "else" condition and take the used fraction of the start day into consideration.