# Countdown to a date excluding weekends and remaining holidays

Tags: c#, time, countdown

I've just started using C Sharp with uni and I wanted to make an app for my dad to countdown for his retirement. So far I have it counting down between the two dates but it only works in days, hours, minutes and seconds, but I can't find how to work weeks.

I'd also like to be able to exclude weekends and his remaining holidays. Any advise?

Copy of my code below, it's not complex but like I said, brand new.

```
  private void Counter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime daysLeft = DateTime.Parse("9/10/2020 3:00:01 PM");
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan t = daysLeft - startDate;
        string countDown = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes, {3} Seconds til launch.", t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);

        Counter.Text = countDown;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating no of weekends in between the two given date and time fields by considering the time difference and output the difference in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801968/calculating-no-of-weekends-in-between-the-two-given-date-and-time-fields-by-cons)  while the questtion isnt exactly the same, its the same logic except you want to count non weekends

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do.
To calculate the number of remaining weeks, divide `t.Days` by 7 and do a little formatting for better representation.
You also can estimate total weekends easily. This can be estimated as following if there are two weekends in every week: `2 * (t.Days \ 7)`.
And for remaining holidays, I think it can be subtracted from the `t.Days` if there is no law limitation (for example maximum of 3 days in a month).
I think with these calculations, your application may become accurate enough for the task.